# Add nodes to linked list that was created from txt file python

Tags: python, linked-list

```
def append(self, data=''):  
    new_node = Node(data)

    if self.head is None:
        self.head = new_node
        return

    last = self.head
    while last.next:    
        last = last.next

    last.next = new_node


linked_list = LinkedList()

with open('All Equipment.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        linked_list.append(line.strip())
```

I have store text file data into linked list by using class node and class Linkedlist. Above is some of my code to store data into linked list.

```
# Add an element to the beginning of the list 
def addFirst(self,data=''):
    newNode = Node(data='') # Create a new node
    newNode.next = self.__head # link the new node with the head
    self.__head = newNode # head points to the new node
    self.__size += 1 # Increase list size



Info = input('Enter your data: ')
linked_list.addFirst(Info)
```

I want to add a new data, put it into nodes and add it at the beginning of the linked listed. Above is some of my code which is a wrong code. What should I change so that user can enter the new data and add it at the beginning of linked list? I new to this task to store data from txt file to linked list so I not quite sure how to make change of the linked list from txt file.

Comment: `new_data = node(data), tmp = self.head, self.head = new_data, new_data.next =tmp.next` aadd at begining

Comment: add after self.__size?

Comment: your  code is also right, what is the issue you are getting though ?

Comment: I have no clue on how to ask user to add their data into linked list. Most of the guide is just manually added into linked list. At the second last line which is Info = input......., I try this to ask user to enter their data, but I don't know how to store it at the beginning of linked list using this addFirst function.

Comment: `linked_list.addFirst(data)` you have to use this.  just add condition there if `self.__head is None: self.__head = new_node`

Answer (score 0):

We didn't get to see your classes, but in the code you shared there are at least these issues:

- In `addFirst` you are creating nodes that always have an empty string as value.

  Change:

  ```
  newNode = Node(data='')
  ```

  to:

  ```
  newNode = Node(data)
  ```
- `addFirst` accesses an attribute called `__head`, while in `append` it is called `head`. This is not consistent.
- `addFirst` maintains an attribute called `__size`, which is not updated in `append`, so when using both methods, `__size` will not be correct.

Comment: After correcting all those command, I have a question. By using this addFirst function,  how can I add data to linked list by asking input from user and adding it at the beginning of linked list? Or is it should be done manually by myself putting the data into the code?

Comment: That is your choice. Both is possible. I'm sure you know how to ask input from the user, since you actually did it with the `input` function in your question's code?

Comment: Ah sorry. What I want to say is after get the input from the user, how can I make it so that the addFirst function will read the input data and add to beginning of linked list. Here I am using the linked_list.addFirst(Info) but it said absolute error. Thats where I stuck.

Comment: "absolute error"? Can you give the exact error message? If your question is about an error that occurs, please make sure your question has all the code needed (but not more) to *reproduce* the error. So you'd need to add the `class` definitions, with at least the constructors (`__init__`)... The idea is that we must be able to run the code as provided (without having to add stuff) and see the error occur.

Comment: My bad. It was Attribute Error: 'LinkedList' object has no attribute 'addFirst'. I will edit my question next time to add the beginning of my code after this.

Comment: OK, that really needs more code, as that means you didn't define `addFirst` as a method of `LinkedList`, but as a standalone function.